# XSLT Transformation using flat file

Tags: java, arrays, xml, xslt

Need some inputs on the below problem.
I have a flat file which contains Accounts numbers

```
Account1:Valid 
Account2:Valid 
Account3:Invalid
```

There is another system generated XML whose contents are transformed in Java via a Transformer class through an XSL file. 
I need to enhance the XSL file so that it takes Accounts from flat file into consideration and based on Valid or Invalid status, generate the o/p response XML.

Any pointers on how to approach this? In Java application, I have done simple transformation. But how to enhance to take data from Flat File into consideration  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with the input as shown, then you need to use XSLT 2.0 and later to use `unparsed-text("accounts.txt")` to read in the text file and for instance parse it with `tokenize(unparsed-text("accounts.txt"), '\n')` into lines and/or further with `xsl:analyze-string`.

XSLT 2.0 is supported in Java by Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/.

With XSLT 1.0 all you could do is pass in a string parameter with the file contents and then use the rudimentary string functions in XPath 1.0 and named templates to extract the data.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the clarification .